# Alpha Vantage Pull Only Close Price

Tags: python, pandas, api, alpha-vantage

Good evening,

Does anyone know how to pull exclusively the close price from alpha vantage API?

I have tried this:

```
df, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=CCC,interval='1min', outputsize='full')['5. volume']
```

with no luck.  thank you in advance.  Also didn't find anything in their documentation.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The alpha vantage python module doesn't allow this. You just have to get the entire the data and then extract the relevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha vantage python module doesn't allow this, So we can you can use get_daily function with outputsize as "compact", this will return 100 records,

```
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol="MSFT", outputsize="compact")
```

This is faster than getting all records

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Global Quote function like so

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

This gives you the previous close and it only returns 1 record.

This is how you can use it:

```
# replace the "demo" apikey below with your own key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32004605)